# Restrict access to Microsoft Graph based on IP

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to access data from my Azure AD, including adding and updating users.

Is there any way I can limit access to the Graph API based on the client's IP? So that requests originating from a specific IP or an IP range will be served, and the rest will be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Graph API deployment https://graph.microsoft.com is a public API that is protected by Azure AD. As long as you have a valid access token you are able to call the API and do what the access token says you are allowed to do regardless of where you are. This means access restriction can only be done at Azure AD level during authorization.

If you apps are user interactive then you can try using [Azure AD Conditional Access Location Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition#location-condition-in-policy).

For daemon apps that run on server-side, this case may not apply because they run behind your trusted networks in most cases.